# SOLR boost documents based on distance and age

Tags: solr

Here is the structure of the solr document

```
   <doc>
     <str name="latlong">52.401790,4.936660</str>
     <date name="dateOfBirth">1993-12-09T00:00:00Z</date>
   </doc>
```

would like to search for document's based on the following weighted criteria..

- distance 0-10miles weight 40
- distance 10miles and above weight 20
- Age  0-20years weight 20
- Age 20years and above weight 10

any ideas on best ways to build the SOLR queries for this?